# Dynamically set the src of an iframe to delay loading

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a page with multiple links and multiple iframes. I have managed to get the iframes to be hidden normally and then become visible when the corresponding link is clicked.

However, as there are quite a few iframes, I would like them only to load once they are visible. At the moment they are all loading when the page first loads, making it a bit slow.

I am trying to fill the `src` of the iframe only when its link has been clicked, but I can't seem to manage it. I either get none of them loading, or them all loading every time any link is clicked.

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a href="#index1" class="index-topic">Topic Name</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#index2" class="index-topic">Topic Name</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#index3" class="index-topic">Topic Name</a> </li>
</ul>

<section id="index1" class="index-content">
  <div>
    Some text about the topic
  </div>
  <div>
    <iframe class="data-embed" data-src="data-source-URL" src=""></iframe>
  </div>
</section>
```

```js
$('.index-topic').click(function(e) {
  //Prevent scrolling of page on click
  event.preventDefault();

  //This is the section that isn't working:
  $(this).find('iframe').attr("src", function() {
    return $(this).data("src");
  });

  //Toggle target tab
  $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: You're trying to "find" the `iframe` in the clicked `<a>`. Try to use the element you're adding the `active` class instead ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `find()` on `this`, which refers to the `a` which was clicked and the `iframe` is not a descendant of that element.

To fix this you can use the `href` attribute of the clicked `a` as the selector.

```js
$('.index-topic').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let selector = $(this).attr('href');
  $(selector).find('iframe').prop("src", function() {
    return $(this).data("src");
  }).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a href="#index1" class="index-topic">Topic Name</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#index2" class="index-topic">Topic Name</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#index3" class="index-topic">Topic Name</a> </li>
</ul>

<section id="index1" class="index-content">
  <div>
    Some text about the topic
  </div>
  <div>
    <iframe class="data-embed" data-src="data-source-URL" src=""></iframe>
  </div>
</section>
```